# How do you run scripts and output results to file in sequence using a shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have the below code in a `.sh` file:

```
/tmp/dev/cpvSSK2/LDN/Grade/003/_runTheBatch2.sh > 
/tmp/dev/cpvSSK2/LDN/Grade/003/batchRun_003.txt;
/tmp/dev/cpvSSK2/LDN/Grade/004/_runTheBatch2.sh > 
/tmp/dev/cpvSSK2/LDN/Grade/004/batchRun_004.txt;
```

when I run the `.sh` file from the command line it just gets stuck at the first command.

It does generate the `batchRun_003.txt` file in the destination folder. However it just stalls at that satge.

Thanks

Comment: output in a file is done by `command > filename`

Comment: Perhaps your command is not truly batch and requires some interactivity? Try redirecting `stdin`.

Comment: Aside from @alvits suggestion, you also could trace the execution (`bash -x ...`) to see *where* it hangs.